# why my file systems shows -71G and how can i fix it

Tags: freebsd, filesystem-corruption

```
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ada0p2      1G    624M    302M    67%    /
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/ada0p4    503M     20k    463M     0%    /tmp
/dev/ada0p5    9.9G    1.7G    7.3G    19%    /var
/dev/ada0p6    903G    903G    -71G   109%    /usr
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /var/named/dev
```

Comment: What happens when you run fsck?

Comment: Which OS is that? You tagged it [linux], but it doesn't look like Linux.

Comment: Linux freebsd 9.0

Comment: There's no such thing as Linux FreeBSD.

Comment: i meant am using FreeBSD as the linux distro

Comment: Does indeed look like the normal FreeBSD naming convention. Retagged. Tempted to also tag it "Linux version windows 10".

Comment: @don, FreeBSD is NOT a Linux distribution, in the same way that Windows is not a Linux distribution.

Comment: DistroWatch should add `Mac OS X BSD/Linux` to their listing ;)

Comment: Windows is now an Ubuntu spin-off now btw.

Comment: I would suggest investigating what takes so much space, try this: `cd /usr` then `du -sm *`. It will show how much each folder/file takes in MB. Then for folders that are suspicious do the same, `cd folder`, `du -sm *`. I suspect `/usr/home` to be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your filesystem usually has some reserved space for root. E.g. an 100MB filesystem might claim 10% full with 9MB data, 20% with 18MB etc all the way up to 100% full with 90MB data.

Only root (or uid 0 processed) can write the remaining reserved space and it will display as over 100% full.

So basically, you wrote data to it as root or a toor and it got full and appears to be over 100%.

Now the big questions for you are:

1. What wrote all that data? Which files are filling up your disk?
2. And if du and find seems to find less: Do you have open but deleted files? (whose data will not be removed from disk until their handle is released).

Both of these have been asked before and more details to them can be found in onther answers here on [su].